# Can MethodInfo be used as Dictionary key?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm wondering whether MethodInfo is suitable for use as dictionary key. From my very limited test, everything seems fine, but is there any gotcha here?

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Well, the equals/gethashcode is most likely based on the reference to the object, not the method it represents.  IF that's good enough for you it may be fine, if not, then you probably want to look deeper.

Comment: @Servy: Is there some caching internally though? It's possible that every call to GetMethod for the same method yields the same object...

Comment: You can test it yourself. Create two separate objects and see what happens if you try Equals or ==

Comment: @Szymon But even if it works once doesn't mean that it will always work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MethodInfo is an abstract class so your question is not directly answerable.  The most common case is where you obtained a reference with Reflection, you get a RuntimeMethodInfo instance.  And yes, it has an elaborate override for the Equals() method, as well as GetHashCode().  It deals with the special case of the method being generic.  The linked blog post is only relevant for GetCurrentMethod().  Use the debugger to find the concrete class type.