# Can MethodInfo safely be used for dictionary keys?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to use `MethodInfo` instances as dictionary keys but I am not able to verify that this is well supported by the .net runtime.

To be more precise, given two `RuntimeMethodInfo` instances `m1` & `m2` that were obtained from the .net reflection API and are representing the same method. Does the .net runtime always guarantees `m1.GetHashCode() == m2.GetHashCode()` and `m1.Equals(m2)` ?

**I could find the same question on stackoverflow :** [Can MethodInfo be used as Dictionary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851565/can-methodinfo-be-used-as-dictionary-key/)

The answer claims that, yes, `MethodInfo` can be used for dictionary keys. However I was unable to verify this claim.

Looking at [the source code of RuntimeMethodInfo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/11868166a541b2746eb86b8812302bd65ecfd2f7/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs#L163), it appears that the implementation of `GetHashCode()` simply calls the default implementation of `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()` (when the method is not generic).

If my understanding is correct `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()`, is only guaranteed to return identical hash codes when objects references are the same.

If my assumption is correct, this would mean that `MethodInfo` cannot safely be used as a dictionary key unless the reflection API is always guaranteed to return the same `MethodInfo` instance for the same given method. Is there any official documentation that would confirm this guarantee ?

Comment: What sort of verification are you looking for? The user that posted the accepted answer in your linked question is a Windows Master Ninja. If you don't believe him, what would you accept?

Comment: Have you done any kind of experiment that can be used to verify/confute your thesis?

Comment: With reflection you query the type system of the runtime, which is heavily cached. Yes, two `GetMethod()` calls will return the same instance. I'm not sure this is documented anywhere though.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! I indeed noticed that `GetMethod` calls seem to produce the same `MethodInfo` instance but I could not find any official source that would confirm that this is guaranteed by the runtime. I could for example imagine this is a side effect of an optimization aimed to reduce memory allocations. My code could then break with some corner cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the best choice here will be to check a C# standard and a documentation. As for documentation - there is no any guarantees there about the return value of GetMethod. So, will the same calls return the same or different instances of MethodInfo is implementation specific. Will the MethodInfo.Equals consider different instances, describing the same methods really equals or not? There is also no explicit guarantees in documentation, so I prefer to consider this also implementation specific.

Resume: for POC/MVP you can use MethodInfo as keys, because the current implementation does all needed to use it as keys. But in cases of any long-living/cross-platform/etc projects, I suggest do not use MethodInfo as keys because behaviour may be changed in the future or may be already different today, but for other runtime.